# Vimium - navigation inside input fields

Tags: google-chrome, vim

When I'm using Vimium, is there a way to navigate (e.g left or right) inside text inputs without arrow keys?

Maybe something like 'h' or 'l', or 'Ctrl+h', 'Ctrl+l'.

Answer (score 9):

Vimium's behavior is in line with Vim's behavior: you have to use the arrows to move around while in insert mode. Note that Vimium's focus is on navigation and interaction with the browser, *not* on text editing.

If you feel the authors/maintainers should implement that kind of feature, feel free to explain them why in [a formal feature request](https://github.com/philc/vimium/issues).

In the mean time, you could try:

- [TextAid](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/textaid/ppoadiihggafnhokfkpphojggcdigllp?hl=en) to edit text directly in GVim/MacVim,
- [Wasavi](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/wasavi/dgogifpkoilgiofhhhodbodcfgomelhe) to turn textfields into vi clones (I didn't know about it before, interesting),
- [Vrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vrome/godjoomfiimiddapohpmfklhgmbfffjj?hl=en) as an alternative to Vimium, note that it uses Emacs keys.

Comment: Vrome is nice but seem to conflict with Vimium. I've added a feature request to Vimium: https://github.com/philc/vimium/issues/956

Comment: Vrome and Vimium have exactly the same purpose. Use one or the other.

Comment: Currently Vimium fits me better so I'm still without input field shortcuts.

Comment: I am using Vimium and Wasavi combination in Chrome, works great!. Thanks for the awesome developers who created it.

Answer (score 2):

Actually you can just press "f" to show short symbols in page, then you'll see your input box has symbol like link, and type it inside input box

Answer (score 0):

My current Ubuntu specific solution is changing my Keyboard Theme to emacs with [gnome-tweak-tool](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gnome-tweak-tool/).

This allows me to navigate inside input boxes with some [emacs bindings](http://ss64.com/bash/syntax-keyboard.html) like `Ctrl-E`, `Ctrl-A`, `Ctrl-Shift-A`, `Ctrl-F`, `Ctrl-B`, etc.

The change in `gnome-tweak-tool` is in `Keyboard and Mouse` -> `Key theme`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can navigate input fields with `<tab>`-key (forward) and `Shift+<tab>` (backwards): `gi<tab><tab><S-Tab>`

Answer (score 0):

If you use the open link keyboard shortcut, I think it is 'f' by default, you can then use that to nav into any field, but doesn't allow you to move to the next one

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).